# How to answer Read-Host for a PowerShell script invoked from C# code

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-4.8

I have a script who is using Read-Host to take a string input from user for some business logic.

But when running PowerShell script from c# code. It is throwing error that "A command that prompts the user failed because the host program or the command type does not support user interaction."

Please help.

Comment: Can you show a [mre] ?  (this should make clear why you do not use `Console.ReadLine()`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839286/how-to-answer-to-read-host-from-c-sharp-code-that-invoked-that-powershell-script

Comment: @mclayton but the code is not working do you know where I can find complete working code?

Comment: Have you looked at the duplicate question? It's almost identical and has a code sample in the accepted answer...

Comment: @NikhilBadhan you either need to spawn a `powershell.exe` process to host the code and I/O pipes (like in the answer mclayton linked), or you need to implement [your own host application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart?view=powershell-7.2) with [support for interactive cmdlets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.ihostsupportsinteractivesession?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thank you for suggestion. The solution works fine for console application but as I am trying to invoke the script from WPF application it is showing error for "Invalid Handle". Do you know any solution?